# Rule of inference - Biconditional proposition

Tags: logic, satisfiability

I'm having trouble with one of the questions given as an assignment which is to
prove:
 $$(p\land q)\leftrightarrow(r\land s), \neg r\land q \vdash \neg p$$

I guess I should use proof by contradiction starting with 'assuming $p$'.
I haven't really seen biconditional proposition from textbook examples and I can't even find one.

Using biconditional elimination,
$$(p\land q)\leftrightarrow(r\land s)$$

is logically equivalent to 
$$\big((p\land q)\to(r\land s)\big)\land\big((r\land s)\to(p\land q)\big)$$

I can't step forward to next step.

Comment: Without some reference for while rules of inference you are using, this question can't be answered.  The most obvious answer is "truth table", or you could infer $r = \bot$ and $q = \top$ from the second statement.

Comment: Assuming $p$ works ... Unpack the biconditional in first premise and derive $\lnot r$ and $q$ from 2nd premise by $\land$-elimination. Now, with $p$ and $q$, derive $p \land q$ by $\land$-intro and derive $r \land s$ by $\to$-elimination. Now apply again $\land$-elim to derive $r$. Having $r$ and $\lnot r$ we can conclude with the negation of the assumption, i.e. $\lnot p$.

Answer (score 0):

Possible sketch for a proof, where $\Sigma=\left\{(p\land q)\leftrightarrow(r\land s),(\neg r\land q)\right\}$:

> 1. $(p\land q)\leftrightarrow(r\land s)\vdash(p\land q)\to(r\land s)$ $\quad$ [$\leftrightarrow$-elimination]
> 2. $\neg r\land q\vdash\neg r$ $\quad$ [$\land$-elimination]
> 3. $\Sigma\vdash\neg r\lor\neg s$ $\quad$ [$\lor$-introduction 2]
> 4. $\Sigma\vdash\neg(r\land s)$ $\quad$ [De Morgan 3]
> 5. $\Sigma\vdash\neg(r\land s)\to\neg(p\land q)$ $\quad$ [Contrapositive 1]
> 6. $\Sigma\vdash\neg(p\land q)$ $\quad$ [Modus Ponens 4-5]
> 7. $\Sigma\vdash\neg p\lor\neg q$ $\quad$ [De Morgan 6]
> 8. $\neg r\land q\vdash q$ $\quad$ [$\land$-elimination]
> 9. $\Sigma\vdash\neg p$ $\quad$ [Disjunction 7-8]